# Kingfisher Swift Compiler error when Archiving

Tags: xcode, kingfisher, ios15, swift-compiler

I'm using `xCode 13 beta` 4 and want to archive my project containing `Kingfisher`.
The app runs fine under `iOS 15`, however I get the following errors when I look to archive it. Anyone with an idea what I should do? Thanks!

[image: Swift compiler error.. available in iOS 13 or newer]

Comment: `AnyCancellable` is from Combine framework. And it works only for ios 13 and above. Set your deployment target in your Project Settings to above ios 13

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Xcode 13, here is a workaround.

If you need to use Xcode 13 but cannot upgrade to v7, use the version6-xcode13 branch. However, you have to drop iOS 10 support due to an Xcode 13 bug.

```
pod 'Kingfisher', :git => 'https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.git', :branch => 'version6-xcode13'
```

Answer (score 4):

Having Xcode 13 upgrade, after pod update, I start getting the same issue as you, after a workaround, I found two ways:

1. Downgrade Kingfisher to 5.x like:

   pod 'Kingfisher', '~>5.15.7'

OR

2. In Deployment Info, upgrade your iOS support version to 12.0

Waiting for any fix from Kingfisher, I opted for downgrading to 5.x

Comment: Need to update both app and Kingfisher, Deployment Info, support version to 12.0

Answer (score 2):

This script worked for me on Xcode 13

```
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
        t.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Kingfisher 7.0.0 beta version should solve it.

E.g. `pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 7.0'`